# Getting more than 4 gamepads working in your Unity game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, gamepad

Unity 2020.1.17f1
Input System 1.0.2

So if I plug in 5 xbox 360 controllers (wired) and 1 modern wireless xbox controller (I think series X or something) I am able to play games such as Regular Human Basketball (which was made in Unity) with 6 players.

However for my own game, Unity is only detecting 4 of those controller max (i.e. Gamepad.all.Count always returns 4 even when all 6 plugged in). I have tried connecting the series X controller with an xbox dongle instead of directly via the laptop bluetooth and still the limit of 4 seems to exist. Basically the first 4 controllers to connect are the ones that Unity seems to recognize and any additional ones are ignored.

Does anyone know why my game is only detecting 4 controllers? It must be possible to detect and play with all 6 in Unity games if other Unity games such as Regular Human Basketball have done it right?

Any advice much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you may need to take the DirectInput route, there is at least "hearsay" that the input system [has this limitation](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-wont-detect-more-than-4-xbox-one-controllers.886312/). does `Input.GetJoystickNames()` return all device names, or only four as well?

Comment: and another legacy info that would back that up (limit of 4, except directinput): https://discussions.unity.com/t/joystick-count-limit/61813

Comment: Thanks. It seems all 6 come back with Input.GetJoystickNames(). That's old input system though right? So will I have to use some sort of a hybrid between new and old input system to get this all working?